# Finding all possible intersections of two lists

Tags: list, haskell, intersection

Say I have a list [2,4,1,5,4] and a list [2,4,5,1] then I wish to have an intersect function that will give me all possible intersections. So the function will output a list of [[2,4,1,5], [2,1,5,4]] in this case.

The built in intersect will give me [4,2,1,5,4].

I have tried to start by making a function

`intersect' xs ys = xs \\ (xs \\ ys)`

This only gives me one of the possibilities -  [2,1,5,4].

I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: You need all possible intersections. So I think you may produce the power set of your intersection. You may use Guava -http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html

Comment: @Razib, isn't Guava a *Java* library?

Comment: Sorry - what is Guava?

Comment: hques12, if I'm not mistaken it's completely irrelevant. Can you explain better what you mean by "all possible intersections"?

Comment: So if I have a list1 where order matters - here [2,4,1,5,4] and a list2 which can be in any order [2,4,5,1] then I wish to have a function that will produce  the subsequences of list1 that contain all the elements in list 2. But if an element is in list1 twice then it will need to be in list 2 twice in order to be included twice.

Comment: Now I've written that I think that maybe I could use the subsequences function in some way?

Comment: `intersect'' xs ys = [x | x <- subsequences xs, length x == length ys, intersect' x ys == x]` might work I think

Comment: hques12, are you only looking for ways you can rearrange one list so that it becomes a subsequence of the other? Or are you also interested in more general things where neither is a submultiset of the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using your second list like a multi-set, let's make that explicit in the type:

```
intersections :: Ord a => [a] -> MultiSet a -> [[a]]
```

The only intersection of a list and an empty multi-set is the empty list

```
intersections _ m | M.null m = [[]]
```

There's no intersections of an empty list and a non-empty multi-set

```
intersections [] _ = []
```

Given a non-empty list and a non-empty multiset, we have all the intersections that use the first item, and all the intersections that don't

```
intersections (a:as) m = with ++ without
```

If the first item in the list isn't in the multiset, then there's no intersections that use it

```
  where with = case M.lookup a m of
          Nothing -> []
```

If it is in the multi-set, then then the intersections that use that item are just extensions of the intersections of the rest of the list and the multi-set after removing one instance of that item,

```
          Just n -> map (a:) . intersections as $ update a (n-1) m
```

The intersections that don't use the item are easily defined by recursion

```
        without = intersections as m
```

And for completeness, a definition of multi-set:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import qualified Data.List as L

type MultiSet a = M.Map a Int

fromList :: Ord a => [a] -> MultiSet a
fromList = L.foldl' (\m a -> M.insertWith' (+) a 1 m) M.empty

toList :: MultiSet a -> [a]
toList = concatMap (uncurry $ flip replicate) . M.toList

update :: Ord a => a -> Int -> MultiSet a -> MultiSet a
update a 0 = M.delete a
update a n = M.insert a n
```

Answer (score 0):

> The built in intersect will give me [4,2,1,5,4].

And from `[4,2,1,5,4]` you can get `[[2,4,1,5], [2,1,5,4]]` using this function:

```
uniqs :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
uniqs  []    = [[]]
uniqs (x:xs)
    | x `elem` xs = map (x:) (uniqs (filter (/= x) xs)) ++ uniqs xs
    | otherwise   = map (x:) (uniqs xs)
```

Then your `intersections` is simply

```
intersections :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]
intersections xs ys = uniqs (intersect xs ys)
```

Comment: note that this will be quadratic, as we're doing repeated linear searches using `elem`.